# Mounting block device driver module on linux stopped working

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, block-device

I make block device driver module and insert module on Ubuntu. And then I want to mount that module as file system using 'mkfs'command. But, `mkfs` command didn't work more with following message:

> writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information

Answer (score 0):

`mkfs` doesn't mount block devices. It creates filsystems on them. (I hope that there was nothing interesting on you device; `mkfs` has deleted the data on block device). To mount a block devices (or better to say to mount the filesystem that is on the blockdevice) you must use `mount`:

```
# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

(presuming `/dev/sda1` is the device you try to mount).

Don't forget to unmount the device when you need it no more:

```
# umount /mnt
```